# Is resolved vs has been resolved?

Tags: grammar, differences

If someone reports an defect to me and is asking for an update, how should I reply?

I will inform you once the issue is resolved or I will inform you once the issue has been resolved?

Comment: I think either way is fine, but "has been resolved" sounds a little more natural to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If something *has been* resolved, and remains resolved, then it *is* (currently)resolved.

Answer (score 0):

It *is resolved* sounds OK, but, it *has been resolved* sounds more familiar

Answer (score 0):

"Someone has resolved the issue" becomes "The issue has been resolved (by.....)" in passive voice. It is Present Perfect tense.

Someone resolves the issue....in passive voice becomes....'The issue is resolved by....' This is Simple Present tense.

In the doubt, "...is resolved/ has been resolved..." looks interchangeable (in this context; but not always). 
Let us see similar examples in active voice; 
Someone has resolved the issue; Someone resolves the issue. There is a difference, which will be so in their P.V.too.

Answer (score 0):

[image: ngram][image: hyper collocations]  Both are interchangeable but "it is resolved" is more frequently used. Besides, "before it is resolved" is correct while "before it has been resolved" is unacceptable.[image: hyper collocations]